# How to list products that belong to more than 3 private categories

Tags: sql

[image]

What's the SQL to find the list of products that belong to more than 3 private categories.

I tried this:

```sql
SELECT
    products.*
FROM
    products
    INNER JOIN
    product_categories
    ON 
        products.product_id = product_categories.product_id
    INNER JOIN
    categories
    ON 
        product_categories.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE
    categories.is_private = 1
GROUP BY
    categories.category_id
HAVING
    COUNT(categories.category_id) > 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty basic `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: I tried many things without good results.

Answer (score 1):

you need every product witch .... so you should do group by on productID.also you can add other columns of products that you need in both 'select' and 'group by'

```
SELECT
    products.product_id,products.name
FROM
    products
    INNER JOIN
    product_categories
    ON 
        products.product_id = product_categories.product_id
    INNER JOIN
    categories
    ON 
        product_categories.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE
    categories.is_private = 1
GROUP BY
    products.product_id,products.name
HAVING
    COUNT (categories.category_id) > 3
```

Comment: If you only return the product_id, you can remove the relation with products and just return product_categories.product_id

Comment: yes.but you can add other columns of product in both 'select' and 'group by' if you need them

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but there is a typo in the last line. Could you add the missing "(".

Answer (score 1):

Your query would be correct if you aggregated by `products.product_id` -- well, depending on the database, you might need to include other columns in the `SELECT`.  But it is valid SQL assuming that `product_id` is unique in that table.

If you only want the product ids you don't need the `products` table:

```
select pc.product_id
from product_categories pc join
     categories c
     on pc.category_id = c.category_id
where is_private = 1
group by pc.product_id
having count(*) > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all columns of products:

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products p
WHERE product_id in (SELECT pc.product_id
                       FROM product_categories pc
                      INNER JOIN categories c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
                      WHERE c.is_private = 1
                      GROUP BY c.category_id
                     HAVING COUNT(c.category_id) > 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out!

```
select * from products where product_id in 
(select pc.product_id from product_categories inner join categories c on 
pc.category_id=c.category_id where c.is_private=1 
group by c.category_id having count(c.category_id)>3)
```